# How to debug react project generated by jhipster at intellij-idea?

Tags: java, reactjs, intellij-idea, jhipster, remote-debugging

How do I debug a react application generated by jhipster at intellij-idea?

Using built in debug at intellij-idea I can debug only the backend. I want to debug the front-end at same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug it using instructions from https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/:

- start your app in a way you normally do this (`./mvnw`, `npm start` or whatever way you normally use)
- create a [Javascript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.1/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) with your server URL, like:

[image]

- add breakpoints in your client code
- debug the configuration above